# Ошибка при записи транзакции в БД PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Привет, коллеги.
В логах возникает ошибка при записи транзакции 
MSK ERROR:  could not obtain lock on row in relation "transactions_20170116"
как это можно исправить, буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Наверное запись заблокирована другой транзакцией? Пересмотрите уровни изоляции и блокировки транзакций.

Comment: Я не совсем дружу с БД Postgresql, где это можно посмотреть ?

Comment: Изоляции и блокировки являются можно сказать стандартом, который поддерживают практически все БД, со своими правда особенностями. Можете поискать общее описание теории, и конкретно как это работает с postgresql,неожиданно так, можно обнаружить в документации по postgresql. И на самом деле, если что-то заблокировалось, то кто-то явно применял блокировки. По умолчанию такого не бывает.